zsh: command not found inside VSCode terminal
Python version 3.13.00 on MacOS
Visual Studio Code first installation
First lines of code, run it, everything is ok... but zsh:command not found:"variable name" when I try to recall it in the terminal
(https://i.sstatic.net/kEfrwthb.png)
Open terminal and go to base directory using cd ~
Then, vim ~/.zshrc inorder to edit the file
Press i for making an insertion and paste the string export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin" at the end
Save and close using :wq
Once this is done, paste source ~/.zshrc

you typed gas in your terminal, what did you expect to happen?

You are typing Python code in System terminal(zsh). If you are trying to recall the code line by line you need to do it in Python interactive terminal. Type python and seeing >>>on the terminal starting point you are good to go.
